# Remove all occurrences of a key in json file

Tags: python, json

How do I remove all occurrences of a key in a json file? In the example below I want to remove all of the "rating" keys.

How it is now:

```
{
  "player": {
    "rating": "99",
    "rarity": "super_rare"
  },
  "player2": {
    "rating": "87",
    "rarity": "rare"
  }
}
```

What I want:

```
{
  "player": {
    "rarity": "super_rare"
  },
  "player2": {
    "rarity": "rare"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as fp:
    data = json.loads(fp.read())
    for player in data.values():
        del player['rating']

with open('output.json', 'w') as fw:
    json.dump(data, fw, indent=4)
```

**Output:**

```
{'abc': {'rarity': 'super_rare'}, 'efg': {'rarity': 'rare'}}
```

Comment: I think `loads` takes JSON string instead of file name.

Comment: `player` is variable name not string. It  loop through all the keys of dictionary

Comment: What if I want to open a .json file, modify the data, and then save the new .json?